How can I add subtotal columns to inquiry grid?
I have a request to add subtotal columns to a grid - and I've seen this in the Project screen's 'Balances' tab - but I can't find any examples of just how to do this:

Does example code exist somewhere that I can use to add this feature?
Thanks much...

You can use public IEnumerable balanceRecords() function from ProjectEntry.cs (App_Data/CodeRepository/PX.Objects/PM/ProjectEntry.cs )as an example.
This is the view delegate of BalanceRecords view.
Bold CSS style is added in PM301000.aspx.cs (Pages/PM/PM301000.aspx.cs )file, take a look at Page_Load and ProjectBalanceGrid_RowDataBound functions there.
